# $type (aggregation) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate-functions

I am checking the data types of one field in several documents that belong to a collection. Fortunately MongoDB has documentation related in that topic [MongoLink](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/). The problem is that I do not understant the output of the aggregation operation.

This is the collection

```
{ _id: 0, a : 8 }
{ _id: 1, a : [ 41.63, 88.19 ] }
{ _id: 2, a : { a : "apple", b : "banana", c: "carrot" } }
{ _id: 3, a :  "caribou" }
{ _id: 4, a : NumberLong(71) }
{ _id: 5 }
```

this is the aggregation operation

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $project: {
       a : { $type: "$a" }
    }
}])
```

and the result is

```
{ _id: 0, "a" : "double" }
{ _id: 1, "a" : "array" }
{ _id: 2, "a" : "object" }
{ _id: 3, "a" : "string" }
{ _id: 4, "a" : "long" }
{ _id: 5, "a" : "missing" }
```

The bits that I do not understant: (i) is the plain letter "a" not the $a in the aggregation function and (ii) the letter "a" that is in the result which is guess is not related with the $a in the aggregation function.

Best Regards

Comment: Do you wanted to know about the difference between `a` & `$a` ? In project stage you're creating a field named `a` which will have value i.e; **type** of existing `a` field's value. When you use `$` like `$a` then it means you're referring to a field named `a` in the document to get it's value. You need to keep in mind that operators in MongoDB may also start with `$` but in general you don't need to wrap them in `" "` but you need to wrap field references in quotes..

Comment: That explanation that you gave me is enough, probably the MongoDB documentation must make slight modifications in the examples to avoid confusion.